# Facebook Like Button - Comment box "flyout" unresponsive

Tags: html, css, facebook, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've trawled the many FB like button threads on here, but can't see this issue.

I have added a FB like button to my page, following the FB Developers instructions.

JS Fiddle here: `http://jsfiddle.net/kitsonbroadhurst/9hamfavb/2/`

I have been laying out my page using bootstrap like this:

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <!-- Social Media Bar -->
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-1">
            <div class="a social-media">
                <div class="a fb-like" data-href="https://enhanceddd.com/article.html" data-width="55" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Main Article -->
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h1>Article Title Goes Here</h1>
                    <img class="a img-main" src="" alt="Article image"/>
                    <h2>First Title - Right here!</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et dolor eget tortor auctor ornaquam imperdiet arcu tellus, eu pretium lacus dignissim eget. Curabitur viverra mollis viverra. Etiam eget quam diam. Integer facilisis odio sit amet commodo placerat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
                <!-- Sidebar Right - Article Links -->
                <div class="relevant-articles col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">
                    <img class="img-relevant" src="images/other-articles400.png" alt="Holding Image"/>
                    <img class="img-relevant" src="images/other-articles400.png" alt="Holding Image"/>
                    <img class="img-relevant" src="images/other-articles400.png" alt="Holding Image"/>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.social-media {
  top: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 65px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  position: fixed;
}

.img-main {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

.relevant-articles {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 800px;
}

.img-relevant {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

When a user clicks like, the comment "flyout" option appears but is unresponsive. It displays behind the main content div to the right.

Could someone help me make sure that the comment "flyout" is always on top?

I tried applying a higher z-index to the social media column, but it had no effect.

**Note: You have to like and then confirm to see the issue, the like will not show up on your FB timeline!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reviewed the use of z-index and have managed to make it work.

I applied a z-index of 2 to the social media "wrapper" div which kept the like "flyout" on top!

```
.social-media {
  top: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 65px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

JSFiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/kitsonbroadhurst/9hamfavb/3/`

Apologies for my lack of css knowledge!